# Is it possible to perform Car Hire availability from Itinerary segments using Sabre SOAP API?

Tags: .net, soap, sabre

I'd like the option to be able to search for Car Hire availability by simply providing the itinerary segments in the background PNR record. You can do this with the following native command (where "1/2" identifies the start and end segments):

```
CF1/2
```

I've looked through the available SOAP APIs and cannot find an endpoint that supports this command, anyone else know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the locations from the air segments (TravelItineraryReadRQ) and use them in a Car Avail request as PickUpLocation and DropOffLocation   (OTA_VehAvailRateLLSRQ)

Comment: And actually this is basically what I have ended up doing and it works ok, just would be a lot less hassle if I could send up the segment numbers

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use SabreCommandLLSRQ for that as there is no specific service that generates the CF1 host entry.

Comment: That's a shame, I don't think parsing the textual response from SabreCommandLLSRQ will be an option in our case. Hopefully a future version of the SOAP API can include this command

Comment: Pretty sure you could asked the support HD to request the devs for an enhancement to an already existing service or maybe even a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that in a true optimized workflow ideal solution should be to parse the information from the Itinerary as mentioned above, and truly making the Car Find requested based on this information( more a stateless call), than based on the segment number workflow that is more replicating human interaction.